# Laravel route go wrong function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using Laravel 5.4 and VueJS. when I config route. I can go to create and show function in controller fine. However, problem with destroy and update function. Although I see this method is PUT or DELETE, it does not work. I try to debug by echo "show" in function show and I got response is "show".

[image: Here is my header]

Here is my code in Vue

```js
onSubmit() {
            let form = new Form_(this.recorddata);
            if (!this.recorddata.id) {
                form.post(this.link).then(response => {
                
                    this.$parent.$parent.pushRecord(response, null);
                    this.$parent.$parent.changeStatusModal(0);
                    this.errors = {};
                })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.errors = form.errors.errors;
                    });
            } else {
                let idRecord = this.recorddata.id;
                form.put(this.link + '/' + idRecord).then(response => {
                    this.$parent.$parent.pushRecord(response, idRecord);
                    this.$parent.$parent.changeStatusModal(0);
                    this.errors = {};
                })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.errors = form.errors.errors;
                    });
            }
        },
```

[image: here is my code in Vue]

in my form.js file

```js
onSubmmit(requestType, url){
        $('.loading-button').button('loading');
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            axios[requestType](url, this.data())
                .then(response => {
                    if(response.data.redirect){
                      window.location.href = response.data.redirect;
                    }else{
                      this.onSuccess(response.data);
                      resolve(response.data);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.onFail(error.response.data);
                    reject(error.response.data);
                });
        });
    }
```

Last, I confirm that I can work fine in my local. I guess my problem is about my hosting. Because I deploy my project into a share hosting. I do not have full permission on vps. I only access it over filezilla. here I my structure in hosting.

[image]

As you see, Laravel folder is a folder contains all of file project except folder "public". All of files in folder "public" is locate in folder public_html.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: thanks for remind, @halfer. I will have experience for the next time.